# Plotting a Regression Line Without Extracting Each Coefficient Separately

Tags: r, plot

For my Stats class, we are using R to compute all of our statistics, and we are working with numeric data that also has a categorical factor. The way we currently are plotting fitted lines is with `lm()` and then looking at the summary to grab the coefficients manually, create a mesh, and then use the `lines()` function. I am wanting a way to do this easier. I have seen the `predict()` function, but not how to use this along with categories.

For example, the data set found [here](http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/bank.txt) has 2 numerical variables, and one categorical. I want to be able plot the line of best fit for men and women in this set without having to extract each coefficient individually, as below in my current code.

```
bank<-read.table("http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/bank.txt",header=TRUE)

fit <-lm(salary~years*gender,data=bank)
summary(fit)

yearhat<-seq(0,max(bank$salary),length=1000)
salaryfemalehat=fit$coefficients[1]+fit$coefficients[2]*yearhat
salarymalehat=(fit$coefficients[1]+fit$coefficients[3])+(fit$coefficients[2]+fit$coefficients[4])*yearhat
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you have, you can get the same predicted values with

```
yearhat<-seq(0,max(bank$salary),length=1000)
salaryfemalehat <- predict(fit, data.frame(years=yearhat, gender="Female"))
salarymalehat <- predict(fit, data.frame(years=yearhat, gender="Male"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement MrFlick, in case of more levels we can try:

```
dat <- mtcars 
dat$cyl <- as.factor(dat$cyl)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp*cyl, data = dat)

plot(dat$disp, dat$mpg)
with(dat,
  for(i in levels(cyl)){
      lines(disp, predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(disp = disp, cyl = i))
            , col = which(levels(cyl) == i))
  }
)
```

[image]